# Y min value on Dual Axis Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set the minimum y value for a dual axis chart. I understand having dual axis is not entirely best practices when plotting, but this is a requested item. I'd like to try and have the minimum set to anything above zero.

Looking online I have not found an answer other than adjusting or using `expansion`. The issue with this is, since it contracts, anything not in the area gets cut off. The plot was made using tenubrand's answer here.
[ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)

I thought his use of y max values in his post could be changed to min but it didn't work. So I included expansion, but it's not dynamic and doesn't work well for varying data sets. Some graphs even cut of at some points.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
# Function factory for secondary axis transforms
train_sec <- function(primary, secondary, na.rm = TRUE) {
  from <- range(secondary, na.rm = na.rm)
  to   <- range(primary, na.rm = na.rm)
  forward <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = from, to = to)
  }
  reverse <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = to, to = from)
  }
  list(fwd = forward, rev = reverse)
}


sec <- with(economics, train_sec(unemploy, psavert))


ggplot(economics, aes(date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = unemploy), colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = sec$fwd(psavert)), colour = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, 
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(-.2, .1)),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~sec$rev(.), name = "psavert"))
```

Comment: Initial thought — sounds like you might want to control the limits using coord_cartesian instead of scale_y_continuous if you don’t want any data excluded (but it’s ok if any of it is potentially out of view). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198613/r-ggplot-boxplot-change-y-axis-limit/28199268#28199268

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: I was just looking at your recommendation, I think I'm close. I have ``coord_cartesian`` set dynamically following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555095/ggplot-modify-coord-cartesian-values-dynamically. It works, but it only adjusts the bar graph, the line graph on the same plot cuts out midway in the plot. If I can have them both adjusted, that would be my ideal output. @JonSpring thanks for the help by the way

Answer (score 1):

One simple option that works for some (many?) situations would be to hardcode the scaling min for both ranges as zero, so that the two series share a vertical origin.

```
train_sec <- function(primary, secondary, na.rm = TRUE) {
  from <- range(secondary, na.rm = na.rm)
  from[1] = 0
  to   <- range(primary, na.rm = na.rm)
  to[1] = 0
  forward <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = from, to = to) 
  }
  reverse <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = to, to = from)
  }
  list(fwd = forward, rev = reverse)
}

ggplot(economics, aes(date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = unemploy), colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = sec$fwd(psavert)), colour = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~sec$rev(.), name = "psavert"))
```

[image]

Comment: Assume I want the graph's y axis to begin at something other than '0', for both axis' (hence setting the y min). How would I do that? Is it even possible to set dynamically?

Comment: I am sure it is possible, but the algebra to correctly account for scale padding in the two scales is breaking my brain right now.

Comment: haha i totally understand, i've been on this longer than i've hoped

Comment: I suspect the answer is something like "low end of secondary range = pmax(0, original_min of secondary range, expanded out 5% from median of secondary range)"

Comment: i'll look into that, you've been more than helpful, thanks